# Pouchdb in Ionic 2 RC.0 is not working

Tags: angular, ionic2, pouchdb, cloudant

I am using pouchdb in Ionic 2 Rc.0 to sync data from cloudantdb.

> I install pouch db using: `npm install pouchdb --save`
>
> I install SQLITE Plugin: onic plugin add `https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage`
>
> I install typings for pouch db:
> `typings install --global --save dt~pouchdb dt~pouchdb-adapter-websql dt~pouchdb-browser dt~pouchdb-core dt~pouchdb-http dt~pouchdb-mapreduce dt~pouchdb-node dt~pouchdb-replication`
>
> I also run the following command to generate a Data service:`ionic g provider Data`

My data.ts file is

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import * as PouchDB from 'pouchdb';
@Injectable()
export class Data {
data: any;
db: any;
remote: any;
username: any;
password: any;

constructor(public http: Http) {
console.log('Hello Data Provider');
this.db = new PouchDB('swqms');
this.username = 'xxx';
this.password = 'xxx';
this.remote = 'https://xxx-bluemix.cloudant.com/xxx';

let options = {
  live: true,
  retry: true,
  continuous: true,
  auth: {
    username: this.username,
    password: this.password
   }
  };

this.db.sync(this.remote, options);

}

addDocument(doc){
this.db.put(doc);
} 

getDocuments(){

console.log("Yes");

return new Promise(resolve => {

  this.db.allDocs({

    include_docs: true

   }).then((result) => {
     console.log("resutl = " + JSON.stringify(result))
     this.data = [];

     let docs = result.rows.map((row) => {
      this.data.push(row.doc);
      resolve(this.data);
    });

     this.db.changes({live: true, since: 'now', include_docs:                   true}).on('change', (change) => {
      this.handleChange(change);
     });

     }).catch((error) => {

     console.log(error);

     }); 

     });


     }

    handleChange(change){

    let changedDoc = null;
    let changedIndex = null;

     this.data.forEach((doc, index) => {

     if(doc._id === change.id){
    changedDoc = doc;
    changedIndex = index;
     }

       });

//A document was deleted
if(change.deleted){
  this.data.splice(changedIndex, 1);
} 
else {

  //A document was updated
  if(changedDoc){
    this.data[changedIndex] = change.doc;
  } 
  //A document was added
  else {
    this.data.push(change.doc);        
  }

  }

  }  

  }
```

My app.module.ts file is

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core'; 
import { IonicApp, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { MyApp } from './app.component'; 
import {Storage} from '@ionic/storage';
import {Data} from '../providers/data';

@NgModule({
declarations: [
MyApp,
AboutPage,
ContactPage,
HomePage,
TabsPage
],
imports: [
IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
],
bootstrap: [IonicApp],
entryComponents: [
MyApp,
AboutPage,
ContactPage,
HomePage,
TabsPage
],
providers: [Storage, Data]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

My app.component.ts file is:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar } from 'ionic-native';
import {Data} from '../providers/data';

@Component({
template: `<ion-nav [root]="rootPage"></ion-nav>`,

providers: [Data]
})
export class MyApp {
rootPage = TabsPage;

constructor(platform: Platform) {
platform.ready().then(() => {
StatusBar.styleDefault();
});
}
}
```

There is some problem in data.ts file.
If I comment this line  `this.db = new PouchDB('sqwms');` default app is showing on the screen (data is not syncing obv)
but when I uncomment this line nothing is showing on the screen.

Someone please help me out. Thanks.

Comment: Do you see errors in the console?

Answer (score 0):

There have to be some errors in the console (of the browser, if you use `ionic serve`) and in your terminal during the build process, which will give you more information about the problem.

Most likely, there is a problem with Rollup, which bundles the code since RC0. See  [App Build Scripts](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/resources/app-scripts/) in the official Ionic docs, where in section "Third Party Modules Export Errors" a custom rollup config file is explained. They use PouchDB as an example.

Answer (score 0):

the error was:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: 'extend' is not exported by node_modules/js-extend/extend.js (imported by node_modules/pouchdb/lib/index-browser.es.js)

The new release of pouchdb 6.0.7 has resolved this error. I updated my npm module and now it is working perfectly.